# Parallel.ForEach making HTTPWebRequests / WebClient broken in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, task-parallel-library, webclient, parallel.foreach, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have written a small program that just makes 2000+ request in parallel.

Scenarios:

1. DotNet Core 3.1: it freezes completely after 900 requests and starts throwing System.Net.WebException(s).
2. DotNet Framework 4.7.2: it runs just fine.

- I have also tried to make a list of tasks and add each task in the `Parallel.ForEach` and then wait for all tasks to complete (`Task.WhenAll(tasks)`) after the `Parallel.ForEach`, with same results.
- I also tried to make the requests using an HttpWebRequest and reading the response instead of using the WebClient, also with same results.

Is this a DotNet Core 3.1 issue or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code that I am running in both scenarios.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\temp\parallel_requests"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\temp\parallel_requests");

    // List with the request urls (simulated, in real life these urls will be the ones that we need)
    var urls = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        urls.Add(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    }

    // Get the requests in parallel
    var random = new Random();
    Parallel.ForEach(urls, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, url =>
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            var jsonString = client.DownloadString(url);
            File.WriteAllText($@"C:\temp\parallel_requests\response_{DateTime.Now:yyyy.MM.dd_HH-mm-ss.fff}_{random.Next(10000, 99999)}.ok.json", $"{url}\n{jsonString}");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            File.WriteAllText($@"C:\temp\parallel_requests\response_{DateTime.Now:yyyy.MM.dd_HH-mm-ss.fff}_{random.Next(10000, 99999)}.err.txt", $"{url}\n{err.Message}");
        }
    });

    Debugger.Break();
}
```

Here are 2 screenshots with a short summary for both scenarios.

[image: .Net Core 3.1]
[image: .Net Framework 4.7.2]

Comment: Do the `System.Net.WebException` details / callstacks give any hints?  You should post an example (as text, not image) of one exception details and its callstack.

Comment: @Milky Could you please the value of the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`. Maybe you have throttled by the OS for the outbound connections.

Comment: @ChrisO Hi Chris, here is the StackTrace:
```
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at SandBox.ProgramNetCore.<GetJsonAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\dev\ProgramNetCore.cs:line 81
```

Comment: @PeterCsala Hi Peter,
The actual value of ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit is 2.
I have played with it, increasing it to 4, 10, 20... but still the same issue in the .Net Core 3.1 application.
The .Net Framework 4.7.1 runs fine even with ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 2

Comment: @Chris Here is the System.Net.WebException Message (sorry it is in spanish):
Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder. Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder.

Comment: @ChrisO I have also tried using the WebClient.DownloadStringAsync with the DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler += OnDownloadStringCompleted
but with same results. Here is the StackTrace
---
   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary() in /_/src/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync/src/System/ComponentModel/AsyncCompletedEvent.cs:line 25
   at System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.get_Result() in /_/src/System.Net.WebClient/src/System/Net/WebClient.cs:line 2080
   at SandBox.ProgramNetCore.<OnDownloadStringCompleted>d__11.MoveNext()
---

Comment: Have you tried using HttpClient? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Miky Have you tried to monitor TCP connections while the application is running? For example via [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview). It shows you that which outbound connection is in which state.

Comment: @NikitaChayka Hi Nikita. Thanks for the hint. Using a global HttpClient solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @NikitaChayka for your hint.

Using a global HttpClient and changing the Parallel.ForEach to AsParallel().ForAll() solved the issue.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\temp\parallel_requests"))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\temp\parallel_requests");

    // List with the request urls (simulated, in real life these urls will be the ones that we need)
    var urls = new List<string>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        urls.Add(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    }

    // Get the requests in parallel
    var client = new HttpClient();
    urls.AsParallel().ForAll(url =>
    {
        try
        {
            var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            File.WriteAllText($@"C:\temp\parallel_requests\response_{DateTime.Now:yyyy.MM.dd_HH-mm-ss.fff}_{Guid.NewGuid()}.ok.json", $"{url}\n{jsonString}");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            File.WriteAllText($@"C:\temp\parallel_requests\response_{DateTime.Now:yyyy.MM.dd_HH-mm-ss.fff}_{Guid.NewGuid()}.err.txt", $"{url}\n{err.Message}");
        }
    });

    Debugger.Break();
}
```